# Accessing all the nodes in TreeView Control

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a `TreeView` Control with set of nodes and child nodes. For example:

> ROOT has A,B,C.

A has a1, a2, a3 and then that a1, a2 also contains some nodes like x1, x2, x3 and so on. Like this many subnodes are there. I know it is possible to use loops with a for loop.

I just want to access all the nodes in `TreeView` control using one or two for loops.

Is there any algorithm for that or is there any other way?

One more question: Is it is possible to have the path of a tree node in an object or in a string using any library functions? For example:

```
string S = TreeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Nodes
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't use nested loops, but go for an recursive solution like:

```
void ListNodes( TreeNode node )
{
  foreach( var subnode in node.Nodes )
  {
    ListNodes( subnode );
  }
  // Print out node
}
```

Call this function for your root node.

For your additional question: check the `FullPath` property.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a recursive function to traverse the whole tree:

```
private void Traverse(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", node.Name, node.FullPath);
        Traverse(node.Nodes);
    }
}
```

You can then call this using:

```
Traverse(treeView.Nodes);
```

and it will walk the whole tree depth first (ie. going down as deep as it can before moving to the next sibling). Passing in the `Nodes` collection means that this code will deal with trees that have multiple root nodes.

The example code above will print out the name of the node as well as the **full path** of that node within the tree.

Answer (score 5):

I am not the biggest fan of recursion but it seems you must use it.  I saw a clever example online mixing recursion with an iterator.

```
    private int GetLevels(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes)
    {
        int level = 0;
        foreach (TreeNode node in TreeTopDown(treeNodes))
        {
            int i = node.Level;
            if (i > level) level = i;
        }
        return level;
    }

    //TopDown Iterator 
    private IEnumerable<TreeNode> TreeTopDown(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeNodes)
        {
            yield return node;
            foreach (TreeNode subNode in TreeTopDown(node.Nodes)) yield return subNode;               
        }
    }

    //BottomUp Iterator
    private IEnumerable<TreeNode> TreeBottomUp(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeNodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode subNode in TreeBottomUp(node.Nodes)) yield return subNode;
            yield return node;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) that returns a `List<TreeNode>`.

**Descendants Extension Method**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeView tree)
    {
        var nodes = tree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>();
        return nodes.SelectMany(x => x.Descendants()).Concat(nodes).ToList();
    }

    public static List<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeNode node)
    {
        var nodes = node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList();
        return nodes.SelectMany(x => Descendants(x)).Concat(nodes).ToList();
    }
}
```

To get all nodes of a TreeView

```
var nodes = this.treeView1.Descendants();
```

To get all child nodes of a Node

```
var nodes = this.treeView1.Nodes[0].Descendants();
```

You can also use linq to search between nodes.

**Ancestors Extension Method**

To get ancestors of a node, you may also me interested to [Ancestors extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805732/3110834).

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is quite old and my method doesn't exactly reduce the amount of recursion *and* it may be slightly slower but it makes my code a bit cleaner.

I use an extension method for `IEnumarable<>` to flatten any tree (not just TreeView nodes):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> rootNodes, 
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenFunction)
{
    return rootNodes.SelectMany(
        child => new[] { child }
            .Concat((childrenFunction(child) ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>())
            .Flatten(childrenFunction)));
}
```

I then use this method to get all the nodes of the tree:

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode> allNodes = treeView1.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>()
    .Flatten<TreeNode>(n => n.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>());
```

Comment: This looks very tidy...Can it be converted to VB.NET?  Can VB use the => operator?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Queue like what i had done in my application :

```
List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
Queue<TreeNode> queue = new Queue<TreeNode>();

//
// first insert all the root nodes into the queue.
//
foreach(TreeNode root in tree.Nodes) {
    queue.Enqueue(root);
}

while(queue.Count > 0) {
    TreeNode node = queue.Dequeue();
    if(node != null) {
        //
        // Add the node to the list of nodes.
        //
        nodes.Add(node);

        if(node.Nodes != null && node.Nodes.Count > 0) {
            //
            // Enqueue the child nodes.
            //
            foreach(TreeNode child in node.Nodes) {
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is used for traversing a TreeView's nodes and returning only the leaf nodes:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> LeafNodes(TreeNode root)
{
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        TreeNode current = stack.Pop();
        if (current.Nodes.Count == 0)
        {
            yield return current;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (TreeNode child in current.Nodes)
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use it for accessing the filenames in an explorer-like TreeView:

```
private void LogFileNames()
{
    //There may be more than one node at root level
    foreach (TreeNode rootNode in FileTreeView.Nodes)
    {
        //Print only filenames, not directories
        foreach (TreeNode leafNode in LeafNodes(rootNode))
        {
            Logger.Info(leafNode.Text);
        }
    }
}
```