# How to select a Node by Tag in Windows Forms TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to select a node by tag. I've searched what I can, but still with no luck. I used this to assign a tag to each node in my `treeview`

```
 foreach (DataRow dataRow in databaseFunc.dataTable.Rows)
 {
      TreeNode nodes = new TreeNode();
      nodes.Text = dataRow["LastName"].ToString().Trim() + ", " +
            dataRow["FirstName"].ToString().Trim();
      nodes.Tag = dataRow[0].ToString().Trim();
      treeView.Nodes.Add(nodes);
 }
```

I know you can select a node using:

```
 TreeNodeCollection nodeCollect = treeView.Nodes;
 treeView.SelectedNode = nodeCollect[index];
```

Comment: Use keys when creating nodes. If they are unique, then you will be able to select by key.

Comment: The Tag property is useless, use the TreeNode.Name property instead.  No need to recurse to find it back, it lights up the ContainsKey() method and the indexer, just as you planned.  Poor naming btw, they should have called it TreeNode.Key instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Find By Tag**

Finding by `Tag` is useful specially when the `Tag` contains a complex object or you want to find based on a non-string key.

To be able to search on child nodes, you can take a look at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360956/3110834) and use `Descendants` extension method to find all nodes including child nodes. Then you can find the node by `Tag`. For example if the `Tag` contains a `Product` and you want to find the product based on its `Id`, you can use such code:

```
var result = tree.Descendants().Where(x=>((x.Tag as Product) != null) &&
                                     (x.Tag as Product).Id = someId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or for a simple string search key:

```
var result = tree.Descendants().Where(x=>(x.Tag as string) == searchkey).FirstOrDefault();
if(result!=null)
    tree.SelectedNode = result;
```

If you want to search just between root nodes, use:

```
var result = tree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(... the rest is like above.
```

**Find By Name**

You can use [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `Nodes` collection to find a node based on its [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.name(v=vs.110).aspx)(not the Text). Using `Find` method is useful when you want to find a node based on a string key. To do so, you should set the `Name` of node when you create the node.

```
var result = tree.Nodes.Find(searchKey , true).FirstOrDefault();
if(result !=null)
    tree.SelectedNode = result;
```

If you want to search just between root nodes, use:

```
var result = tree.Nodes.Find(searchKey , false).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Note**

As a conclusion you can use the `Tag` property to store a complex object in `Tag` and unbox it when you need. For string search keys, it's better to use `Name` property as said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228617/how-to-select-a-node-by-tag-in-winforms-c-sharp#comment56201370_34228617).