# Treeview Node Text and specified key are matching strings but don't 'match'

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to add a child node to a parent node in a treeview. I'm finding the loan name by specific key `loanresult.LoanName` to the node text. Both show as "TestOne" however the child is not being added to the parent tree node.

Matches then throws the error `matches[0].Nodes = 'matches[0].Nodes' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'` due to no matches being found.

```
foreach (string st in activityList)
{
    var activityResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(st);
    if (loanResult.LoanName == activityResult.ParentLoanName)
    {
        TreeNode[] matches = tvTodoList.Nodes.Find(loanResult.LoanName, false);
        if (matches.Length > 0) matches[0].Nodes.Add(activityResult.ActivityName);
    }
}
```

Text

[image]

Key

[image]

I must be missing something obvious here?

Comment: You should assign the key to `Name` property. The `Text` property is for showing text, `Name` will be used as a key, so you can find the node by its key. Also when finding, if you want to find in all nodes including descendants, pass `true` as second parameter: `var node = treeView1.Nodes.Find("some key", true).FirstOrDefault();` then check `if(node!=null)` then do something. See *Find By Name* example in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34228733/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using single parameter constructor, use an overload with two parameters as following

```
//matches[0].Nodes.Add ("Your Key", "Node Text to display")
matches[0].Nodes.Add(loanResult.LoanName,activityResult.ActivityName);
```

Because you are not specifying any key while adding new node hence, it is not able to search any node by key.

Comment: Turns out I wasn't giving each node a key and text. I had                 `tvTodoList.Nodes.Add(loanResult.LoanName);` which was only assigning the text to each node with the name being an empty string `""`. By adding `tvTodoList.Nodes.Add(loanResult.LoanName, loanResult.LoanName);` gave me the desired results.