# How to get Text from all Parent Nodes of a Node in TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Maybe I couldn't explain well, but this should explain:
I have a int field called getParentNode(TreeNode) to get how many parent it has (e.g if there is 2 nodes below node, count will be 2)
And I have a List field called getParentNames(TreeNode) that returns all of the parent's names.

*getParentCount:*

```
int getParentCount(TreeNode node)
{
    int count = 1;
    while (node.Parent != null)
    {
        count++;
        node = node.Parent;
    }
    return count;
}
```

*getParentsNames:*

```
List<string> getParentNames(TreeNode node)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getParentCount(node); i++)
    {
        //i = 1 : list.Add(node.Parent.Text);
        //i = 2 : list.Add(node.Parent.Parent.Text);
        //i = 3 ...
    }
    return list;
}
```

Do I need to check if (i == 0) (I don't want to write manually because number can be anything) or something?
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

- Split `FullPath` of node by `PathSeparator` of tree
- Ancestors and AncestorsAndSelf sxtension methods

#### Split `FullPath` of node by `PathSeparator` of tree

You can use `FullPath` property of the `TreeNode` and split the result using `PathSeparator` property of `TreeView`. For example:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    var ancestorsAndSelf = e.Node.FullPath.Split(treeView1.PathSeparator.ToCharArray());
}
```

#### Ancestors and AncestorsAndSelf sxtension methods

Also you can get all ancestors of a `TreeNode`. You can simply use a while loop to go up using `node.Parent` while the parent is not null. I prefer to encapsulate this logic in an extension method and make it more reusable for future. You can create an extension method to return all parent nodes (ancestors) of a node:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public static class TreeViewExtensions
{
    public static List<TreeNode> Ancestors(this TreeNode node)
    {
        return AncestorsInternal(node).Reverse().ToList();
    }
    public static List<TreeNode> AncestorsAndSelf(this TreeNode node)
    {
        return AncestorsInternal(node, true).Reverse().ToList();
    }
    private static IEnumerable<TreeNode> AncestorsInternal(TreeNode node, bool self=false)
    {
        if (self)
            yield return node;
        while (node.Parent != null)
        {
            node = node.Parent;
            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<TreeNode> ancestors = treeView1.SelectedNode.Ancestors();
```

You can get text or any other property from ancestors:

```
List<string> ancestors = treeView1.SelectedNode.Ancestors().Select(x=>x.Text).ToList();
```

**Note**

JFYI you can use an extension method approach to get all child nodes too. Here I've shared an extension method to to so: [Descendants Extension Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360956/3110834).

Comment: Oh, that looks pretty good. But i do not understand that exception method can be called from treeView1.SelectedNode .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)  - **Extension Methods** in fact extend a type and add new method to it. In above scenario after adding `TreeViewExtensions` to your program (in a namespace) and using that namespace in a form, `treeView1.SelectedNode` will have an `Ancestors()` method which you can use to get all ancestors of a node. I used the same technique to also get all [descendants](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32360956/3110834) of a node.

Comment: It's really a clean and elegant mechanism to add new reusable functionality to types. (For example most linq methods are extension methods which doesn't actually exists in `List<T>`, but after using `System.Linq` they will be added to some types like `List<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the `node.FullPath` counting the `TreeView.PathSeparator` char? Something like

```
char ps = Convert.ToChar( TreeView1.PathSeparator);
int nCount = selectedNode.FullPath.Split(ps).Length;
```

Comment: List<string> lst = selectedNode.FullPath.Split(ps).ToList<string>();

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I noticed that I need to use while loop:

```
List<string> getParentNames(TreeNode node)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        int count = getParentCount(node);
        int index = 0;
        TreeNode parent = node;
        while (index < count)
        {
            if (parent != null)
            {
                index++;
                list.Add(parent.Text);
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: [`Ancestors`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39805732/3110834) extension method is much better. It returns a `List<Node>` which you can simply use to get a count or any property of nodes like `Text` from the list.

Comment: Probably you have no idea about what an extension method is or how to use it. [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type.