# How can I get a TreeView child selected node but also the above nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

```
private void treeView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the node that was clicked
    TreeNode selectedNode = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location).Node;

    if (selectedNode != null)
    {

    }
}
```

If I have for example a root node:

```
World
```

When I click on it I see these nodes:

```
World
|____ Blue
|____ Green
|____ Red
|____ Black
|____ yellow
```

If I click on *Blue* I will see more nodes under *Blue* for example

```
World
|____ Blue
|    |____ Day
|    |____ Night
|____ Green
|____ Red
|____ Black
|____ yellow
```

Now if I click on Blue I will get the selected node name *Blue*. `selectedNode.Name` will be *Blue*

And if I click on *Day*  will get in `selectedNode.Name` *Day*
But what I want to do is that if I click on *Day* the `selectedNode` be 
*Blue\Day* or *BlueDay*

And if under *Day* there is another node name *1* and I click on *1* so in *selectedNode.Name* I want to see *BlueDay1* or I prefer *Blue\Day\1*

I want this `\\` so I can use it as a directory name.
The problem is i'm using the `selectedNode.Name` as a directory to get files:

```
List<string> ff = new List<string>();
private void treeView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode selectedNode = treeView1.HitTest(e.Location).Node;

    if (selectedNode != null)
    {
        string tt = mainPath + "\\" + selectedNode.Text;
        ff = DirSearch(tt);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

If I click on Blue then it's fine it will get all the files under Blue including sub directories. But if i click on 1 and there are files in 1 then it will not get any files since i need the complete path name *Blue\Day\1* to get the files from 1.

This is how I'm getting the files

```
static List<string> DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {
                files.Add(f);
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
    return files;
}
```

The idea is if I want to get all the files under Blue I click on Blue but if I want to get only the files in 1 when I click on 1 it's not working since 1 is not the complete path.

Comment: Off-topic, but use `AfterSelect` event instead of `MouseClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `TreeNode` has a [`FullPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.fullpath(v=vs.110).aspx) which gets the path from the root tree node to the current tree node. For example you can see full path of all nodes for a tree like below tree:

```
Tree                Full Path
==============================
1                   1
|__ 11              1\11
    |__ 111         1\11\111
    |__ 112         1\11\112
```

There is a [`PathSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.pathseparator(v=vs.110).aspx) character for `TreeView` which gets or sets the delimiter string that the tree node path uses, which is `\` by default.

If you want to have more control over the path, you can use [`Ancestors`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805732/3110834) or [`AncestorsAndSelf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805732/3110834) extension methods.

In the example I provided below I've created path without the root node:

```
var pathWithoutRootNode = string.Join(@"\", 
    e.Node.AncestorsAndSelf().Where(x => x.Parent != null).Select(x => x.Text))
```

Comment: There is no property AncestorsAndSelf of Node. Where should i get it from or how to use it ? Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'TreeNode' does not contain a definition for 'AncestorsAndSelf' and no extension method 'AncestorsAndSelf' accepting a first argument of type 'TreeNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I've posted the link of [`AncestorsAndSelf`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39805732/3110834) method in answer. It's an extension method which I've written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39805732/3110834).

Comment: I added the TreeViewExtensions to my code and removed the static i got errors if it's static. But still in the event AfterSelect this AncestorsAndSelf not exist: e.Node.AncestorsAndSelf()

Comment: `TreeViewExtensions` should be static because it contains extension methods. I've updated the linked code with required `using`s. Just copy the code in `TreeViewExtensions.cs` and use it anywhere in your projects.

Comment: After you made it working, read more about [C# Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/bb383977.aspx) which let you to add some methods to a class without inheritance. :)

Comment: Working great. Thank you.