# Getting all visible Nodes in a TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I want to get the node's keys just 'only in view' on treeview.

Here is the example;

[image]

I am using below code to get all node recursively. It just return all nodes key as expected. however i need to get the keys that only in treeview's view;

```
public void PrintNodesRecursive(UltraTreeNode oParentNode)
{
    if (oParentNode.Nodes.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach (UltraTreeNode oSubNode in oParentNode.Nodes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(oSubNode.Key.ToString());
        PrintNodesRecursive(oSubNode);
    }
}

private void ultraButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintNodesRecursive(ultraTree1.Nodes[0]);
}
```

I don't know i should follow different path or just reorganize code.

I just stacked after many hours. Need your help.

Comment: Have you tried the `.IsExpanded`, `.IsVisible`, `.NextVisibleNode`, `.PrevVisibleNode` properties of the Treenode? (If I correctly understand the question).

Comment: @Jimi hey, yes i tried next visible node and it works perfect but i didn't  make it in for loop. How can i get all nodes using next visible node programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the first visible node using `Nodes` collection and `IsVisible` property of the `Node`. Then create a recursive method which uses `NextVisibleNode` to find the next visible node in `TreeView`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var visibleNodes = GetVisibleNodes(treeView1).ToList();
}
public IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetVisibleNodes(TreeView t)
{
    var node = t.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().Where(x => x.IsVisible).FirstOrDefault();
    while (node != null)
    {
        var temp = node;
        node = node.NextVisibleNode;
        yield return temp;
    }
}
```

Also as another option, you can rely on [`Descendants`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360956/3110834) extension method to flatten the `TreeView` and then using `IsVisible` property, get all visible nodes.

Comment: Thank you. you made my day. I want to be like you in the near future sir.