# C# winform populate a treeview from a custom struct array

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a custom structure which holds Nodes info(level,index,childCount), and the struct is stored in sequence in a binary file. Now, I need to rebuild the TreeView from the file, I got the structure[] back, but stuck in converting the structure to the nodes. Here is a image,the left part of the image represents the struct array, same as the binary file structure. The right part is the TreeView I want to build.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEKQ8.png)

I only hope someone can give me a tip about the recursive function, since I'm still learning C# :) THANKS.

Comment: you need to include some code to show us where you got stuck

Comment: TreeNode is serializable, why do you need a custom structure to _hold_ its info?

Comment: @TnTinMn The custom structure which is from the binary file, is not my work, I'm kind of working on cracking the file structure.

Comment: you can try this link... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702815/winforms-treeview-with-checked-nodes-recursion/49707471#49707471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function i've made assumes that the leveling always begin at Level 0 based on the image you've provided.

This function also assumes that after a Level 0 item, any value of level, greater than 0 will be considered as a child node of the previously encountered level 0 item.

What i did here is that, i've created a list of TreeNodes and a list of Levels based on your struct, and will loop through the list based on levels, if a level is detected greater than the initially provided level, a recursive call will be made to process the sub levels.

```
 public List<TreeNode> MainNodes(List<Levels> strut, int level){

    List<TreeNode> parentNode = new List<TreeNode>();
    for(int x = 0; x< strut.Count; x++){
        var data = strut[x];
        if(data.Level == level){
            TreeNode nodeC = new TreeNode();
            nodeC.Name = strut[x].Index.ToString(); //Index value from struct
            if(x + 1 < strut.Count){ 
                if(strut[x+1].Level > level){
                    var newArray = new List<Levels>(strut);
                    newArray.RemoveAt(x);
                    nodeC.Nodes.AddRange(MainNodes(newArray, level + 1);
                }
            }
            parentNode.Add(nodeC);
        }
    }
    return parentNode;
}
```

[image]
This functions returns the nodes and sub-nodes based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but there seems to be a error at first. The Nodes.AddRange() needs TreeNode[] nodes not list<TreeNode>, so I change it to nodeC.Nodes.AddRange(MainNodes(newArray, level + 1).ToArray())

Comment: No worries, just used list for testing, forgot to change it back to array since it was the one you've used, but all ends well :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Name field and Find function.
Name is a key and Find function find a nodes by Name Field.
at first, you need to save a unique key value each nodes. and then you will 
find a node by key and make a hierarchy

Here is sudo code,

```
Treeview myTreeView = new Treeview();

TreeNode parentNode = new TreeNode();  // maybe it will index = 1 , level = 0 in your image
parentNode.Name = "uniquevaule";
myTreeView.nodes.add(parentNode);

TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(); // maybe it will index = 0 , level = 1
childNode.Name = "child";
TreeNode[] nodes = myTreeView.Nodes.Find("uniquevaule", true);
nodes[0].add(childNode);
```